# Subprocess call to execute a complex command

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I need to start the following command in my linux shell.

```
./bin/winexe -U ladmin //135.249.24.214  --interactive=0 --system "cmd.exe /c powershell -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://135.249.21.229/fr_query/base64.tcl','C:\Users\ladmin\Desktop\successshibani456.csv')"
```

However, using `subprocess.call()`, the parentheses and quotes don't match correctly.

Escaping double quotes does not help.

```
subprocess.call("./bin/winexe -U ladmin //135.249.24.214  --interactive=0 --system \"cmd.exe /c powershell -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://135.249.21.229/fr_query/base64.tcl','C:\Users\ladmin\Desktop\successshibani456.csv')"\")
```

Command is executed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error may be in your quote escaping - you have the command as:

```
subprocess.call("./bin/winexe -U ladmin //135.249.24.214  --interactive=0 --system \"cmd.exe /c powershell -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://135.249.21.229/fr_query/base64.tcl','C:\Users\ladmin\Desktop\successshibani456.csv')"\")
```

But maybe it should be:

```
subprocess.call("./bin/winexe -U ladmin //135.249.24.214  --interactive=0 --system \"cmd.exe /c powershell -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://135.249.21.229/fr_query/base64.tcl','C:\Users\ladmin\Desktop\successshibani456.csv')\"")
```

Not how the escape slash on the last double quote is moved to the actual double quote that balances inside the string.

You may also find that you need to escape the backslashes inside of the string too:

```
subprocess.call("./bin/winexe -U ladmin //135.249.24.214  --interactive=0 --system \"cmd.exe /c powershell -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://135.249.21.229/fr_query/base64.tcl','C:\\Users\\ladmin\\Desktop\\successshibani456.csv')\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the `subprocess` module do most of the escaping for you. Can you run the following command and verify if it works? The command has been separated into its component arguments. Because backslash characters are located in the last argument, the strings are written as being raw.

```
completed_process = subprocess.run((
    './bin/winexe',
    '-U',
    'ladmin',
    '//135.249.24.214',
    '--interactive=0',
    '--system',
    r'cmd.exe /c powershell -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('
    r'"http://135.249.21.229/fr_query/base64.tcl",'
    r'"C:\Users\ladmin\Desktop\successshibani456.csv")'
))
```